# How to find all variables of an expression?

Tags: expression-manipulation

Is there a function that can extract a list of variables in an expression?
For example, assume we have an expression

```
x^2+y^3+z
```

This expression has variables x, y and z. The result should be

```
{x, y, z}
```

. Is there a way to get this?

Comment: `Variables` command should work `Variables[x^2 + y^3 + z]`

Comment: What about `x[1]^2 + x[2]^3 + x[3]`? `Variables` works, but none of the present answer do...

Answer (score 11):

For polynomial expressions @Buddha_the_Scientist's suggestion `Variables` will work. For more general expressions

```
expr = x^2 + y^3 + z
DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr, _Symbol, ∞]
```

Should do the trick in most situations.

Comment: Since all symbols are on level -1, you can use `{-1}` , instead of `\[infinity]`.

Comment: Might want to include only symbols in the ``"Global`"`` context.  I'd probably use `Union` instead of `DeleteDuplicates` to get them in canonical order.

Answer (score 8):

The undocumented `` Integrate`getAllVariables `` is a somewhat more robust version of `Variables`. It has a required second argument that specifies a variable to be excluded from the output.  It just goes to show that internal functions are not always defined with the general user in mind.

```
Integrate`getAllVariables[x^2 + y^3 + z, {}] (* delete {} from output: *)
Variables[x^2 + y^3 + z]                     (*   {} can't happen anyway *)
(*
  {x, y, z}
  {x, y, z}
*)
```

A case `Variables` does not handle:

```
Integrate`getAllVariables[{x[0]'[t] + a t == 0, 
  y[1] == Sin[b[t]] x[0][t]^2}, {}]
Variables[{x[0]'[t] + a t == 0, y[1] == Sin@b[t] x[0][t]^2}]
(*
  {a, t, b[t], y[1], x[0][t]}
  {}
*)
```

Note how `b[t]` is treated differently than `Sin[t]`, etc.:

```
Integrate`getAllVariables[a + b[t] - c[t + s] + x^y, {}]
Integrate`getAllVariables[a + Sin[t] - Cos[t + s] + x^y, {}]
(*
  {a, x, y, b[t], c[s + t]}
  {a, s, t, x, y}
*)
```

The second argument is useful in problems in which there is a principal independent variable and you want to get all the others.  Excluding more than one, however, can only be achieved by hacking:

```
Integrate`getAllVariables[x^2 + y^3 + z, x]
(*  {y, z}  *)

xc /: {xc[a__]} := {a};  (* except the variables a.. *)
Integrate`getAllVariables[x^2 + y^3 + z, xc[x, y]]
(*  {z}  *)
```

Comment: It is remarkable that ```Integrate`getAllVariables``` excludes symbols with `NumericFunction` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

I like the following approach x):

```
expr = x^2 + y^3 + z;    
Select[DeleteDuplicates@Level[expr, Depth@expr], Head[#] == Symbol &]
```

the result is:

```
{x, y, z}
```

Answer (score 2):

Listing the expression might be an alternative for this simple example

```
List @@ (x^8 + y^3 + z) /. a_Symbol^n_ -> a
```

Comment: How about `2 x^y - z`?

Comment: Then i prefer Cases[List @@ (2 x^y - z), _Symbol, Infinity]//Union

Comment: List does not matter anymore Cases[(2 x^y - z), _Symbol, Infinity]//Union